# Material not displaying on object

Tags: texturing, shaders

Material I created is not displaying on object. Mode activated on screenshot: material preview.
[image]

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing more of your setup. Is the material you made in the active material slot for the object?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett what happened is that sometimes I add material to an object and then after working with it for about an hour or so - it disappears. Like it's in the active material slot but in render/material preview modes you can't see anything. I wonder what I'm doing wrong or what buttons do I press so that it disappears. 

https://imgur.com/a/wjJivaS

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You will have two materials in the model. Blue material will not show if any other material is above it.

In my screen shot my model is not showing red material because there is blue material above it.

Comment: Tried it just now but it didn't help. : (

Answer (score 0):

I just selected the object that was not showing a material, went into Edit Mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and pressed "Assign" under *Material Properties* and then the material was correctly displayed.

[image]