# Why are my materials not showing on my objects?

Tags: rendering, materials

I tried to use these [solutions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/233103/material-not-displaying-on-object), but my problem was not resolved. How exactly does the material show on the objects? It appears that each cube has a material associated with it, but it's not showing. Here's a screenshot of pretty much everything I'm working with.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just switch to one of these icons:[image] I would recommend you watch some beginner blender tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution! I should definitely watch more tutorials. I was too eager to start playing around with the software!

Comment: @RonSnow No problem !) It's great to test around before watching tutorials, makes the person more independent from tutorials :-)